# Decoherence of a laser beam via oil emulsion

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, laser, refraction, decoherence

This is sort of a followup to [an earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/748350/anti-collimators-for-laser-beams) that I posted regarding how to destroy the temporal and/or spatial coherence of a laser beam. It was suggested to me that I could use a rapidly rotating sheet of ground glass through which I pass the later, which seems useful but a little bit complicated (and it can only destroy the coherence down to a certain point, as mentioned in the comments). This made me think: why couldn't I just pass the laser beam through an oil emulsion instead? Light travels about 14% slower in oil than in water, and I have read the the average oil droplets in an emulsion have a wavelength of 10 um or so, so it seems like the path-length differences created by having some photons travel through oil droplets while others do not would be more than enough to destroy the temporal coherence of a visible-frequency beam. Moreover, it seems like passing through oil droplets would also cause the beam to bend repeatedly, destroying some of the spatial coherence as well.

Am I on to something here? Or do I really need to go with the ground glass in order to achieve optical decoherence?

Comment: An oil emulsion could work. Ground glass is just one convenient way to do it.

Comment: I assume you want to minimise loss of energy from your light beam. No matter what techniques you use, some of the energy will be lost as heat. Since your light source is monochromatic, I *suspect* that diffraction-based scattering will give the best results for your application.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuser_(optics) has some good info. Maybe you could use something based on the principles of the [integrating sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_sphere). Also, there are diffusers that are used with solar light tubes, but they're designed for broad optical spectra, they're not optimised for monochromatic light.